# Python dict in list in tuple iteration

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, tuples

tuple1

```
(
[
{'key1': [val,val,val,val]}, 
{'key2': [val,val,val,val]}
]
)
```

tuple2

```
(
[
{'key2': [val,val,val,val]}, 
{'key1': [val,val,val,val]}
]
)
```

i need to compare both are identical or not.
what i have written is comparing lines.

code:

```
for (a,b) in zip(tuple1,tuple2):
            for (elements,items) in zip(a,b):
                print(elements,items)
                lista = set(a[elements])
                listb = set(b[items])
                pprint(lista)
                pprint(listb)
                sys.exit(1)
                res = lista.union(listb)  - lista.intersection(listb)                
                shared_keys = lista.intersection(listb)
                added = lista - listb    
                removed = listb - lista
                              
        return added,removed
```

Current problem: If a key in tuple1 and tuple2 is shuffled, it says tuple are different but i need to check if both the tuples have that key, and inner value are same or not. if not print the key with values.

Comment: You could sort the lists first e.g. `tuple1.sort(key=lambda d:list(d.keys())[0])`

Comment: Iterate over list of one tuple and check for key in dict of the other list.

Answer (score 0):

Out of my understanding, I came up with this code. I think this might be useful for you:

```
if len(tuple1) != len(tuple2):
    print(False)
else:
    l1, l2 = [], []
    for d1, d2 in tuple1, tuple2:
        l1.append(list(d1.keys()))
        l2.append(list(d2.keys()))
    print(all(e in l2 for e in l1))
```